# Hibernate sessionfactory nullpointerexception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nullpointerexception, sessionfactory

I'm practicing on hibernate. I'm trying to connect local mysql server and get some information but have some error messages on my console. I debugged my code and found the initial part when I'm trying to create a session factory

```
     Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

this part of my code to cause an java.lang.NullPointerException error. I'm pretty sure I have import the all hibernate jars.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN'
      'http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd'>
    <hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>

<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>


<property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name='connection.driver_class'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name='connection.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel</property>
<property name='connection.username'>root</property>
<property name='connection.password'>root123</property>

<property name='cache.provider_class'>org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

<property name='transaction.factory_class'>org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name='current_session_context_class'>thread</property>
<property name='hibernate.show_sql'>false</property>

 <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource='Hotel.hbm.xml'/>
   <mapping resource='Car_Rental.hbm.xml'/>
   <mapping resource='Hotel_Reservation.xml'/>
   <mapping resource='Ticket_Reservation.hbm.xml'/>
   <mapping resource='Tour_Reservation.hbm.xml'/>
   <mapping resource='Touristic_Place.hbm.xml'/>
   <mapping resource='User.hbm.xml'/>

   </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is where I'm trying to build sessionfactory:

```
    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        //Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(new             File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Hotel\\src\\hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Console:

```
    javax/transaction/SystemException
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at screens.Screen_User.save(Screen_User.java:211)
    at screens.Screen_User$1.actionPerformed(Screen_User.java:182)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

I'm working on this for 2 day but I could not figure that out. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: NPE is on `Screen_User.save` method so provide code for that

Comment: I have but I debugged my code wrote the only initial part not all I'm pretty sure issue is right on there.

Comment: use this `serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();`

Comment: Is `Screen_User` a entity class and u trying to save some data through this class???

Comment: I think you should use the comment path of hibernate hbm file configure

Comment: I have tried that before its not working either same error same part.

Comment: @amitbhardwaj , no I'm not I'm using that class just for swing interface I'm saving the data on User class and commit them.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi, I made a mapping on my config xml.

Comment: you have two `cache.provider_class` in your code, is this right?

Comment: @Yogi not sure but I tryed to delete one of them still same error.

Comment: @ArifEzberci sorry, but I don't trust your debugging skills so if you want some help, you better provide code for `Screen_User.save()` method as it is the place where NPE is thrown.